# Adding All Rows Checkbox for Unknown Gridview Data Source

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database, gridview

I have a `Gridview` like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
         Width="16px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        GridLines="Horizontal" Height="16px" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <sortedascendingcellstyle backcolor="#F4F4FD" />
        <sortedascendingheaderstyle backcolor="#5A4C9D" />
        <sorteddescendingcellstyle backcolor="#D8D8F0" />
        <sorteddescendingheaderstyle backcolor="#3E3277" />

<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Programaticly, i adding a data source this `Gridview`.

```
protected void SendToGridview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculate.Visible = true;
        MV_Label.Visible = true;
        RISK_Label.Visible = true;

        string strQuery;
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ora"].ConnectionString;

        OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);

        strQuery = @"SELECT A.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 || '/' || A.TEKLIF_NO2 AS TEKLIF, A.MUS_K_ISIM AS MUSTERI, 
                    B.MARKA, C.SASI_NO, C.SASI_DURUM, D.TAS_MAR, NVL(RISK_SASI(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2, C.URUN_SIRA_NO, C.SIRA_NO),0) AS RISK,
                    NVL(MV_SASI(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2, C.SIRA_NO, C.URUN_SIRA_NO, SYSDATE),0) AS MV
                    FROM S_TEKLIF A,  S_URUN B, S_URUN_DETAY C, KOC_KTMAR_PR D
                    WHERE A.TEKLIF_NO1 || A.TEKLIF_NO2 = B.TEKLIF_NO1 || B.TEKLIF_NO2
                    AND A.TEKLIF_NO1 || A.TEKLIF_NO2 = C.TEKLIF_NO1 || C.TEKLIF_NO2
                    AND B.SIRA_NO = C.URUN_SIRA_NO
                    AND B.DISTRIBUTOR = D.DIST_KOD
                    AND B.MARKA = D.MARKA_KOD
                    AND B.URUN_KOD = D.TAS_KOD ";

        string param = "";
        foreach (ListItem l in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (l.Selected)
            {
                param += string.Format("'{0}'", l.Value);
                param += ",";
            }
        }
        param = param.Remove(param.Length - 1);

        strQuery = strQuery + " AND A.HESAP_NO IN (" + param + ")";

        OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

        myCommand.CommandText = strQuery;

        myConnection.Open();

        OracleDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;

        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

This is my Gridview looks;

[image]

What i want is, i want to add checkboxes column after `RISK` column and `MV` column.

I mean, columns looks like, **HESAP_NO**, **TEKLIF**, **MUSTERI**, **MARKA**, **SASI_NO**, **SASI_DURUM**, **TAS_MAR**, **RISK**, **(CheckBoxes)**, **MV**, **(Checkboxes)**. Totaly should be **11** column.

And i want all checkboxes is checked as a default.

How can i do that?

I read **[this](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs)** article, but in this article Gridview a normal data source. I adding programaticly.

Comment: Gridview is okay for quickly outputting some data, but if you plan to be serious I suggest building your own grid. And while you're at it do yourself a favor and discover an ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to switch `AutoGenerated` columns off and used defined ones instead:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="16px" BackColor="White"
     BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"  
     CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" Height="16px" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

     <!-- put your style stuff here -->

     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="HESAP_NO" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="TEKLIF" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="MUSTERI" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="MARKA" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="SASI_NO" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="SASI_DURAM" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="TAS_MAR" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="RISK" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="Text" />

     <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="NameCheckBoxField1" HeaderText="NameCheckBoxField1" />

     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Text" DataField="MV" />

     <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="NameCheckBoxField2" HeaderText="NameCheckBoxField2" />

</asp:GridView>
```

You will also need to change your SQL to return two fields that the `CheckBoxField` can map to.  Those fields should contain a bit field with true set for all cases.  This will allow the data to be automatically bound to the `CheckBoxField` and checked by default.

EG:

```
SELECT
    -- all our fields
    'NameCheckBoxField1' = 0x1,
    'NameCheckBoxField2' = 0x1
FROM
    -- etc...
```