# Add checkbox column to asp.net gridview programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, stored-procedures

I am loading data to gridview from a stored procedure, what I want is to include a checkbox in the gridview programmatically, I was able to get that through this link [Adding All Rows Checkbox for Unknown Gridview Data Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412638/adding-all-rows-checkbox-for-unknown-gridview-data-source)

**stored pro portion to include the checkbox**

```
select 
   fields...
   'chkApprove' = 0x1
from 
   tablename
```

**gridview defintion in source view asp.net**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdDSTR" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None"
                         BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"  Font-Size="Smaller" 
                        EmptyDataText="No Records Found" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">


      <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Day" DataField="Day" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surcharge" DataField="Surcharge" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Senior" DataField="Senior" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="VES" DataField="VES" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Other" DataField="Other" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Refund" DataField="Refund" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Void" DataField="Void" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="GSC" DataField="GSC" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cash" DataField="Cash" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Charge" DataField="Charge" />
     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Gift" DataField="Gift" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="chkApprove" HeaderText="Approve" />
```

What I noticed is that, the checkboxes per row are disabled, and all are automatically checked by default.

My desired output is only rows who match a condition in the row computation should be checked. How can I create a simple condition like for example when GSC data is above 10,000, the checkbox should be checked? otherwise, leave it unchecked

[image]

Comment: can you show us the code to render the Gridview?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with sample codes. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this solution can help you out [Adding All Rows Checkbox for Unknown Gridview Data Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412638/adding-all-rows-checkbox-for-unknown-gridview-data-source)

Comment: Hi, i follow the example, I got this error right after," The data in the CheckBoxField 'chkApprove' could not be parsed as a boolean value.  Try using a BoundField instead"

Comment: its best to create a new question for this issue you get

Comment: OK, I have updated a new question in related to the previous one, hope you can help. thanks

Comment: If you don't want the checkboxes as disabled then you'll have to use <TemplateField> instead of a <checkfield> used here. <TemplateField> let's you add any editable asp.net control. Next, regarding the checked condition, in the Row_DataBound event of the GridView, you can always find a control and set it's value.